# How to draw rectangles onto a JavaScript video?

Tags: javascript, html, object-detection

I am trying to allow users to upload their own video which will then be displayed into a canvas. From there on, they can draw rectangles onto the canvas (to annotate for object detection), and clear the rectangles when they want to. However, what I want is that when the users draw the rectangles and play the video, the rectangles will follow an object on the video. Also, when the user wants to re-draw the rectangles to reposition them, they will clear the rectangles on the canvas - but the previously-drawn rectangles will already be saved.

This is the current code I have:

```
function update(){
      context.drawImage(video,0,0,1580,700);   
      requestAnimationFrame(update); // wait for the browser to be ready to present another animation fram.       
    }

function readyToPlayVideo(event){ // this is a referance to the video
    // the video may not match the canvas size so find a scale to fit
    videoContainer.scale = Math.min(
                         canvas.width / this.videoWidth, 
                         canvas.height / this.videoHeight); 
    videoContainer.ready = true;
    // the video can be played so hand it off to the display function
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
    // add instruction
    /*document.getElementById("playPause").textContent = "Click video to play/pause.";*/
    document.querySelector(".mute").textContent = "Mute";
}

function updateCanvas(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
    // only draw if loaded and ready
    if(videoContainer !== undefined && videoContainer.ready){ 
        // find the top left of the video on the canvas
        video.muted = muted;
        var scale = videoContainer.scale;
        var vidH = videoContainer.video.videoHeight;
        var vidW = videoContainer.video.videoWidth;
        var top = canvas.height / 2 - (vidH /2 ) * scale;
        var left = canvas.width / 2 - (vidW /2 ) * scale;
        // now just draw the video the correct size
        context.drawImage(videoContainer.video, left, top, vidW * scale, vidH * scale);
        /*if(videoContainer.video.paused){ // if not playing show the paused screen 
            drawPayIcon();
        }*/
    }
    // all done for display 
    // request the next frame in 1/60th of a second
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas2").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var isDrawing = false;
var startX;
var startY;

var mouseIsDown = true;
var mouseIsUp = true;
var startX;
var startY;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    console.log(mouseX,mouseY);
    $("#downlog").html("Down: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    if (mouseIsDown) {
        console.log('1');
        canvas2.style.cursor="crosshair";
        mouseIsDown=false;
        mouseIsUp=false;
        console.log(mouseIsDown);
    } else {
        handleMouseUp();
    }

    mouseIsDown=false;
    mouseIsUp=true;

}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    mouseIsDown=false;
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    if (mouseIsUp) {
    console.log('2');

      context2.beginPath();
      context2.rect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY);
      context2.strokeStyle="limegreen";
      context2.lineWidth=2;
      context2.stroke();
      canvas2.style.cursor="default";
      mouseIsUp=true;
    }

}

$("#canvas2").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});

$("#canvas2").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});

function clearcanvas()
{
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2'),
    context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: this seems like a very very very broad question. I would suggest taking it one step at a time and when you get stuck you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: @AndrewLohr I think for now, I am stuck mostly on how to create rectangles and save them to an array (I believe array should be the way to do it?), as I have a video and not just an image, which basically means that I do not want just one frame of rectangles. Could you help me with that? Thank you!